# Can I Call visualforce page in custom action - CPQ?

Tags: cpq, custom-actions

I am using following custom action for CPQ , I wanted to call my custom visualforce page , could anyone advise how can I call a visualforce page inside custom action.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the URL field on the Custom Action object (you probably need to add it to the page layout or double check the Field Level Security, judging from the screenshot).

Then link to your Visualforce page (`/apex/nameOfVFPage`).

Comment: there is one field named URL Target , which has two options popup and replace page which one to use in this case and in which field should I add /apex/nameOfVFPage

Comment: `URL Target` decides if you get a popup with the VF page in it, or if you are redirected to the VF page. You need to add the url of the VF page in the `URL` field, but as I said, you probably need to add it to the page layout, or edit it using another tool such as the SOQL tab in the developer console.

Comment: ohh got it , FLS was turned off for that field , thanks for your help.

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande can you please provide more details on how you have implemented this? Also if you have ran into any issues?